# c# Export to text file specify column widths for export file

Tags: c#, export-to-csv

I am trying to create an app in C# where a user can fill in the row data manually then press export button and this will export the rows into a text file.

I can get the file to export using the code below but I would like each column to have a specific width when the file is exported.

How would I do this?

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //If you manually add rows to a DataGridView, you must disable the
        //AllowUserToAddRows function.  The function can be enabled after
        //you have added the rows.
        dataGridView1.AllowUserToAddRows = false;

        //The code below adds Columns to the DataGridView control

        DataGridViewColumn colHold = new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
        colHold.Name = "col1";
        colHold.HeaderText = "FIELD1";
        dataGridView1.Columns.Add(colHold);


        colHold = new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();

        colHold.Name = "col2";
        colHold.HeaderText = "FIELD2";
        dataGridView1.Columns.Add(colHold);

        colHold = new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();

        colHold.Name = "col3";
        colHold.HeaderText = "FIELD3";
        dataGridView1.Columns.Add(colHold);

        colHold = new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();

        colHold.Name = "col4";
        colHold.HeaderText = "FIELD4";
        dataGridView1.Columns.Add(colHold);

        //The code below adds rows and fills cells with values to be exported.

        dataGridView1.Rows.Add();

        dataGridView1.Rows[dataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1].Cells[0].Value = "1".PadRight(20);
        dataGridView1.Rows[dataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1].Cells[1].Value = "2";
        dataGridView1.Rows[dataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1].Cells[2].Value = "3";
        dataGridView1.Rows[dataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1].Cells[3].Value = "4";

        dataGridView1.Rows.Add();

        dataGridView1.Rows[dataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1].Cells[0].Value = "5";
        dataGridView1.Rows[dataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1].Cells[1].Value = "6";
        dataGridView1.Rows[dataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1].Cells[2].Value = "7";
        dataGridView1.Rows[dataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1].Cells[3].Value = "8";
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //This line of code creates a text file for the data export.

        System.IO.StreamWriter file = new System.IO.StreamWriter(@"C:\TextFile.csv");           try
        {                
            string sLine = "";


            //This for loop loops through each row in the table
            for (int r = 0; r <= dataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1; r++)
            {
                //This for loop loops through each column, and the row number
                //is passed from the for loop above.
                for (int c = 0; c <= dataGridView1.Columns.Count - 1; c++)
                {
                    sLine = sLine + dataGridView1.Rows[r].Cells[c].Value;
                    if (c != dataGridView1.Columns.Count - 1)
                    {
                        //A comma is added as a text delimiter in order
                        //to separate each field in the text file.
                        //You can choose another character as a delimiter.
                        sLine = sLine + " ";
                    }
                }

                //The exported text is written to the text file, one line at a time.
               file.WriteLine(sLine);                     
               sLine = "";                    
           }

           file.Close();
           System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("Exportlete.", "Program Info", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
        }
        catch (System.Exception err)
        {
            System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(err.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            file.Close();
        }
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: You are asking about exporting yet you display grid code ? Grids are meant to *display* tabular data, not save CSVs or fixed-width files

Comment: Columns width in csv file ?

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this :

```
            int[] columnWidths = { 10, 20, 30 };
            int[] inputData = { 1, 2, 3 };

            string output = string.Join("", inputData.Select((x, i) => new string(' ', (columnWidths[i] - x.ToString().Length)) + x.ToString()).ToArray());
```